# Interpreting the table of classification of the partitions of $n$

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, integer-partitions

I am going through [A NON-RECURSIVE EXPRESSION FOR THE NUMBER OF IRREDUCIBLE REPRESENTATIONS OF THE SYMMETRIC GROUP $S_n$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2098) by AMUNATEGUI. In table I, the classification of the partitions of n according to the numbers of sub-partitions differing from unity is presented. The screenshot is given below.

[image]

I am having trouble in understanding the elements in this table. Let us take the case of the symmetric group $S_n$ which corresponds to the row $p(5)$ in the table. So, what do the values $1, 4, 2$ mean here? How do the values correspond to the partitions mentioned in the following [partition table of $S_n$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S5)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(5)=5,41,32,311,221,2111,11111$

$11111$: $0$ subpartition different  from $1$whose number is $1$)
$41,311,2111,5$ :  $1$ subpartition diff.from $1$( whose number is $4$)
$32,221$: $2$ subpartitions diff.from $1$( whose number is $2$)